# Rails validating attachment extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, format

I'm trying to validate the extension of an attachment. I've tried with the following :

```
 validates_format_of :image_vector, :with => %r{\.(ai|dxf|eps|svg)$}i
```

However it doesn't seem to work, whenever I upload a svg file it says that the format is not valid. I've also tried using paperclip, but can't seem to work the extension out.
Any help would be greately appreciated

Comment: Does it return any errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_format_of :image_vector, :with => %r{\.(ai|dxf|eps|svg)$}i, :message => "whatever"
```

Comment: It wasn't when I posted my solution, you were missing the \ before the period.

Comment: Either :with or :without must be supplied (but not both)

Comment: Sorry, everything that I'm finding online is saying that what you're original code, and what I posted before my edit is the proper way to do it. There must be some other factor not letting it validate.

Answer (score 0):

With paperclip you can do something like that:

```
before_post_process :is_image?

def is_image?
  ["image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/png", "image/x-png", "image/gif"].include?(self.plan_content_type) 
end
```

Maybe you could try it within your context.